# It is possible to change the text color depending on the value? (React native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am working in an app using React native, here goes the code that I am in trouble:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Content, Card, CardItem, Body, Left } from "native-base";
import { PricingCard } from "react-native-elements";

export default class AppBodyData extends Component {
  render() {
    let articles = this.props.data.map(function (articleData, index) {
      return (
        <PricingCard
          //color='#ff3300'
          wrapperStyle={
            articleData.percent_change_1h >= 0 ? styles.green : styles.red
          }
          info={[
            "1h change: " + articleData.percent_change_1h,
            "24h change: " + articleData.percent_change_24h,
            "7days change: " + articleData.percent_change_7d,
          ]}
          button={{
            title: "More information",
            icon: "info",
            backgroundColor: "#4f9deb",
          }}
        />
      );
    });

    return <Content>{articles}</Content>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  green: {
    color: "#00ff00",
  },
  red: {
    color: "#ff0000",
  },
});

module.export = AppBodyData;
```

What I need is that if the `articleData.percent_change_1h` variable is positive **the color of that variable** must be green otherwise must be red.

PricingCard is an object of react-native-elements library: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/pricing/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to manipulate `styles` passed to your `PricingCard's` `wrapperStyle` `prop`.

```
// Stylesheet.
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

// Card.
<PricingCard wrapperStyle={(articleData.percent_change_1h >= 0) ? styles.green : styles.red} ../>

// Styles.
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  green: {
    color: '#00ff00'
  },
  red: {
    color: '#ff0000'
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that I want the variable to change not the hole object

Comment: Ok, sure. My guess would be to manipulate the `color` attribute via `wrapperStyle`.

Comment: I have just upload all my code because with your solutions I get a waring that the key 'color' does not exist in props.wrapperStyle. I have changed color to backgroundColor and it works but it changes all the background and I only want to change the articleData.percent_change_1h value color. Thanks

Comment: Yes I just changed info for a <Text> </Text> tag and linked with that wrapper Style, and it rolls. ;)

Comment: "You could use a ternary operator to manipulate " - Is there a way to manipulate the color based on the prop value for more than two options?

Comment: Meaning can you set the color to the value given by the prop (i.e. set the color to props.customColor so that if props.customColor is 'red' it'll make it red and if it's rgb(235,213,143) then it'll set it to that?