# how to change the color of options in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code for a quiz app with react,

1. I want my options be red if the wrong answer is clicked and be green if the correct answer is clicked, how can I do this?
2. I tried some things but changes will apply to all of the options...how can I prevent this?

this is the react code only and I have the css of course :))))

````
import questions from './questions.json'
import {Fragment} from 'react'
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import isEmpty from '../../utls/is-empty'


 class Play extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            questions,
            currentQuestion:{},
            nextQuestion:{},
            previousQuestion:{},
            answer:'',
            numberOfQuestions:0,
            numberOfAnsweredQuestions:0,
            currentQuestionIndex:0,
            score:0,
            currectAnswers:0,
            wrongAnswers:0,
            hints:5,
            time:{},

         
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const{questions,currentQuestion,previousQuestion,nextQuestion}=this.state;
        this.displayQuestions(questions,currentQuestion,previousQuestion,nextQuestion)
    }
    displayQuestions=(questions=this.state.questions , currentQuestion , nextQuestion,previousQuestion,answer)=>{
        let {currentQuestionIndex}= this.state;
        if(! isEmpty(this.state.questions)){
            questions= this.state.questions;
            currentQuestion=questions[currentQuestionIndex];
            nextQuestion=questions[currentQuestionIndex+1];
            previousQuestion=questions[currentQuestionIndex-1];
            const answer=currentQuestion.answer;
            this.setState({
                currentQuestion,
                nextQuestion,
                previousQuestion,
                answer,
         
            });
        }
    };

    

    handleOptionClick=(e)=>{
        if(e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === this.state.answer.toLowerCase()){
           this.correctAnswer();
        }else{
            this.wrongAnswer();
        }

    }
    
    correctAnswer=()=>{
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            score: prevState.score+1,
            numberOfAnsweredQuestions: prevState.numberOfAnsweredQuestions+1,
            currectAnswers:prevState.currectAnswers+1,
            currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex+1,
            // option_classcorrect: prevState.true
        }))}

    wrongAnswer=()=>{
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            score: prevState.score-1,
            numberOfAnsweredQuestions: prevState.numberOfAnsweredQuestions+1,
            wrongAnswers:prevState.wrongAnswers+1,
             currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex+1,
            
            }))}
    

    render() {
        const {currentQuestion}= this.state;



    return(
         <Fragment>
          <Helmet> <title>Play</title></Helmet> 
                <div className="questions">
                <h2>Questions</h2>
                <div className="container">
                <p>
                    <span></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span></span>
                </p>
                </div>
                <div className="timer-container">
                    <p>
                        <span className='left' style={{float: 'left'}}>1 of 15</span>
                        <span className='right' style={{float: 'right'}}>2:15</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className='current-question'>
                    <h5>{currentQuestion.question}</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="options-container">
                        <p  onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className='option'>{currentQuestion.optionA}</p>
                        <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className='option'>{currentQuestion.optionB}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="options-container">
                        <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className='option'>{currentQuestion.optionC}</p>
                        <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className='option'>{currentQuestion.optionD}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="button-container">
                    <button className="btn-q">previous</button>
                    <button className="btn-q">next</button>
                    <button className="btn-q">Quit</button>
                </div>  

                </div>
        </Fragment>


    )
}}
export default Play```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things I'd do differently on this, but I think the shortest path to the solution from where you currently are would involve passing `currentQuestionIndex` to `correctAnswer` and keeping track of *which* questions have been answered correctly instead of simply tracking how many.

```js
this.correctAnswer(this.state.currentQuestionIndex);
```

```js
correctAnswer=(index)=>{
  this.setState({
    userAnswers: {
      ...this.state.userAnswers, // retain previous state
      [index]: true // set specified index to true to indicate correct
    }
  })
}
```

---

With this in place you could assign a css class predicated on the value of `userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]`:

```
  {/* you'd have to tweak this to account for unanswered questions. omitting it here in the interest of clarity */}
  const answerClass = this.state.userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex] ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';

  <div className=`current-question ${answerClass}`>
    <h5>{currentQuestion.question}</h5>
  </div>
```

```css
.correct {
  color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  color: red;
}
```

---

You could tighten this up further by using the same method for both correct and incorrect:

```js
handleOptionClick=(e)=>{
  const isCorrect = e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === this.state.answer.toLowerCase();
  this.onAnswer(this.state.currentQuestionIndex, isCorrect);
}

onAnswer=(index, isCorrect)=>{
  this.setState({
    userAnswers: {
      ...this.state.userAnswers,
      [index]: isCorrect
    }
  })
}
```

This approach also eliminates the need for `numberOfAnsweredQuestions` and `score` in state, because they can be derived from `userAnswers`:

```js
// gets the number of userAnswers
const numAnswers = Object.values(this.state.userAnswers).length;

// gets the count of userAnswers entries whose value is true
const score = Object.values(this.state.userAnswers).filter(x).length;
```

Comment: when i try the first sooution i got this erorr:

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "this error", but my guess is that it's something about `this.state.userAnswers` not existing. You'll need to either add it to your initial state or make sure it exists before attempting to spread it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles on a component to change the text color based on the users' selection. `style={{color: incorrectColor}}`

You would need to evaluate whether the selected answer is correct or incorrect, update the state, and then update the color on the component.

Take a look at this answer using a ternary operator to manipulate styles: [It is possible to change the text color depending on the value? (React native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904338/it-is-possible-to-change-the-text-color-depending-on-the-value-react-native)